# Unable to log into encrypted Banking website with Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, cryptojs

I have been using Puppeteer to log into a bank website and scrape data of my transactions in a C# application, and it works fine.

However, I am looking for a way to do the same in a simple Azure function.  I was able to get it working by wrapping it in a docker instance, but the expense of the Azure Premium Subscription in order to run it makes it not cost-effective.

I have looked at trying to log into logging into the site and scraping the HTML, except it uses CryptoJS to alter the login credentials, as well as create some unique form properties on the POST message.

So my question is, is it possible to pull out the JS from the website to replicate the encoding with python, so I don't require a full headless browser to log in?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you can do this by using [PyV8](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyv8/), but the easier way out would be to use a headless browser.

Comment: Sure, which is why I had been using Puppeteer.  But I'm trying to get away from it.  Some examples using PyV8 to do this sort of thing would be useful, if you know of any?

Comment: Sure, here are few examples that I think should help you [link](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/97063/PyV8.JSContext)

If you need to call a particular function, just replace the function parameters at call time using string format or you can directly call a function using eval function of PyV8.JSContext

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, the site itself is a Javascript Renderable site, which requires requests-html to render, which in itself uses pyppeteer which is a headless chromium, which won't work in Azure anyway.

So I'm just going to look at alternative hosting and build it as a web API instead of Azure Functions.